# Unexpected EOF in prolog Error

Tags: java, .net, xml, vb.net, soap

I'm attempting to send a SOAP Message to another web service, however the response I get back throws an error: "Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: XML reader error: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog".

The web service is written in Java, with a client written in VB.NET.

```
 Case SoapMessageStage.BeforeDeserialize
 readStr = New StreamReader(oldStream)
 writeStr = New StreamWriter(newStream)
 soapMsg1 = readStr.ReadToEnd()
 xDoc.LoadXml(soapMsg1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your massage is properly escaped and without any forbidden characters?
I got that message a lot from parser if I forgot about it.

Comment: i believe so...can't say 100% though. I get this error when attempting to use a SOAP Extension. When its hits the xDoc.LoadXml(soapMsg1) it breaks initially stating: "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."

When I look at the soapMsg1 String its gives the "Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: XML reader error: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog" error.

I posted a snipped of my code above...

Comment: Check it. Log before parsing, sniff what you are sending. You are probably sending or receiving empty xml(or xml declaration only).